# Swing - Search text within a JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I have a documents that's displayed in a non-editable JTextField , and I want to enable users to search within this document.

I already figured out I could use a custom JTextField for input , and use the HighLight painter to mark the occurrences - But I couldn't help but feeling that this seems like such a common problem that maybe there's a component that does it much better then I can (like cycling through the results, highlighting them in different colors , ignoring case...)

Do you know of any such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwingX comes with complete search support (in a JEditorPane only, sigh: note to myself - how about the other text components?)

Answer (score 2):

The [Swing book](http://www.manning.com/robinson2/) (by Matthew Robinson and Pavel Vorobiev) has a great chapter on [Constructing an HTML Editor Application](http://www.manning-source.com/books/robinson2/robinson2_ch20.pdf) which shows you how you can implement "Find and Replace".